# Incompatible types in assignment, Why can't I do this?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, char

I have a struct The_Word that has a variable char word[WORD_LENGTH]

I have the following

```
typedef struct The_Word
{
    char word[WORD_LENGTH];
    int frequency;
    struct The_Word* next;
} The_Word;

int someFunc(char* word)
{
/*Rest of method excluded*/

struct The_Word *newWord = malloc(sizeof(struct The_Word));

newWord->word = word; // error here. How can I assign the struct's word to the pointer word
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) to copy an string:

```
#include <string.h>

int someFunc(char* word)
{
  /*Rest of method excluded*/

  struct The_Word *newWord = malloc(sizeof(struct The_Word));
  strncpy(newWord->word, word, WORD_LENGTH);
  newWord->word[WORD_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';
}
```

You should be careful to check if the string fits in the array. That's it, when the length of the parameter `char* word` is longer than `WORD_LENGTH`.

Comment: what if WORD_LENGTH > strlen(word)?

Comment: @PrototypeStark that's what the line `newWord->word[WORD_LENGTH - 1] = '\0';` is for.

Comment: no i mean, "word" is 10 characters long(+1 '\0') and WORD_LENGTH = 100? Wouldn't it be a waste of time executing 90 copies?

Comment: @PrototypeStark The function `strncpy` copies at most n bytes. In your example, the function copies just the first 11 characters.

Comment: @PrototypeStark my bad, you are correct, `strncpy` pads with null bytes. However, calling `strlen(word)` does also cost time. If the length of the string is on average longer than `WORD_LENGTH / 2` then is better to use `WORD_LENGTH` instead of `strlen(word)`.

Comment: Better than either is `newWord->word[0] = 0; strncat(newWord->word, word, WORD_LENGTH - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign pointers directly. Instead you should use `strncpy()` function.

```
strncpy(newWord->word,word,strlen(word));
```

`strcpy()`, `memcpy()` all work similarly.

```
typedef struct The_Word
{
    char word[WORD_LENGTH];
    int frequency;
    struct The_Word* next;
} The_Word;

int someFunc(char* word)
{
/*Rest of method excluded*/

  struct The_Word *newWord = malloc(sizeof(struct The_Word));
  memset(newWord->word,0,WORD_LENGTH);
  strcpy(newWord->word,word);
  /*return something*/
}
```

Comment: Ok, why can't I use strcpy(newWord->word,word)?

Comment: You can. @user1738539. I like strncpy() more is all. strcpy() is also valid there.

Comment: You should always check if there is enough space in the array to store the string.

Comment: The `strncpy()` function does not guarantee that the result string is null terminated.  Also, if you copy a 5 byte word into a 20 KiB buffer, `strncpy()` will carefully zero out the remaining 20475 bytes of memory (where `strcpy()` would stop after the sixth byte).  There's a case for saying "_if you can't safely use `memmove()` to copy the string, you can't safely use `strcpy()` or `strncpuy()` either_".

Answer (score 0):

This gives an incompatible types error because in C arrays are treated as constant pointers.  Arrays and pointers are not exactly the same thing.  Although they behave identically in most other circumstances, you cannot reassign what an array points to.

It looks like you intend to copy the string from the function argument into the newly allocated struct.  If this is the case use strncpy() or memcpy() as others have suggested.